# Find out character encoding of file without ending

Tags: ios, encoding

The url below downloads a file without an extention including busstations and times. The data is fetched in an iPhone-app that displays bustimes called mobitime. The problem is that I can't find out what encoding the data is. Is there any way to find out?

Thanks!

http://d2.mobitime.se/cgi/mtc/sad?uuid=01b07052fa390ceb845405e3d0547f7e&r=4&id=191430&no=721&to=Odensbacken%20via%20Ekeby-Almby&lang=sv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two techniques that I know of:

1. You can look at the HTTP headers and see if it reports anything useful:

   ```
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
       if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
           NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (id)response;
           NSLog(@"httpResponse.allHeaderFields = %@", httpResponse.allHeaderFields);
       }
   }];
   ```

   Those headers report `"Content-Type" = "text/plain";` which obviously is not the case.
2. Sometimes you can also use the `usedEncoding` option of one of the `initWithContentsOfURL` method:

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       NSStringEncoding encoding;
       NSError *error;
       NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];

       if (error)
           NSLog(@"%s: initWithContentsOfURL error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

       if (string)
           NSLog(@"encoding = %d", encoding);
   });
   ```

   But that reports an error (suggesting, again, that this might not be a string encoding at all).

In short, I'd suggest you contact the provider of that web service, and ask them regarding the format. But looking at the hex dump, I don't recognize the format. With a passing glance at it, it looks like binary data, not any string encoding.